# Batch search and change in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, replace, refactoring

I need to make a mass change in my vuejs project. I want to make a batch selection and replace with vs code, but there is a point where I am stuck.

this is my current code

```
   fetch('http://example/categories'),
  fetch('http://example/products'),
```

Here is my code after the change

```
   fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_URL}/categories`),
  fetch(`${process.env.VUE_APP_URL}/products`),
```

I can select all example urls, but I need to replace the trailing and leading " ' " with " ` ", but I couldn't find the way. How can I do this, any idea?

Comment: what's preventing you from changing it?

Comment: find: `fetch\('http://.+?/(.+)'\)` with regex on. replace: `fetch(\`${process.env.VUE_APP_URL}/$1\`)`